# Console Application Pizza Slices

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I am writing a program that allows user to enter the diameter of a pizza and the program calculates how many slices the pizza will give you. Here is my code so far.

```
 //DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
        string Diameter = null;           //The diameter of the pizza which the user will enter
        int Slices;                       //The number of slices the user will get
        const double SliceSize = 14.125;  //The area of each slice of pizza
        double Radius;                    //The radius of the pizza
        double Area;                      //The area of the pizza


        //INPUT
        Console.WriteLine("Enter diameter of pizza:");
        Diameter = Console.ReadLine();
        double Diameter1 = Convert.ToDouble(Diameter);

        //PROCESS
        Radius = Diameter1 / 2;
        Area = Math.PI*Math.Pow(Radius,2);
        Slices = (int)(Area / SliceSize);

        //OUTPUT
        Console.WriteLine("A Diameter\" pizza will yeild {0:n0} slices", Slices);


        // END - pause the program so the user can read the output and waits for user to press any key to exit the console
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

How do I round up the output and how to I reference the diameter of the pizza diameter in the output writeline?

Comment: What is the matter with the program? Does it compile, does it run?

Comment: What is wrong? Also, the amount of slices isnt dependant of the diameter of pizza.

Comment: No it does not compile. The error msg says" cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: of course it is dependant on the diameter! the bigger your pizza the more slices you can cut with a reasonably edible surface, hmmm I'm getting hungry..

Comment: @a13xy - so cast it to an int...

Answer (score 2):

- As @GeorgeDuckett mentioned, you're not setting radius, thus, you're getting an error that says `Use of unassigned local variable 'radius'`
- You're attempting to divide two doubles and store the result in an int `slices = area/pizzaslice;` so you get the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`.

The error list is your friend. Read the errors & **Google them** if you don't understand what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the `radius` variable anywhere. You should be using `decimal.Parse` to set it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter diameter of pizza:"); 

diasize = Console.ReadLine();
var radius = 0;    
if (decimal.TryParse(diasize, out radius))
{
    radius =/ 2;
}
```

You also need change `slices = area/pizzaslice;` to `slices = (int)(area/pizzaslice);` since slices is an integer and the result of `area/pizzaslice` is a double.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already ointed out some of your coding errors.  You also have logic errors.  Have a careful look at these two lines:

```
radius = Math.Pow(radius,2)*Math.PI;
radius /= 2;
```

What are you trying to do here?  What are you actually doing?

Remember the formulas for the diameter and area of a circle:

```
diameter = 2 * radius

area = pi * radius^2
```

Now go back and look again at what your code is doing.

Comment: 'Area = Math.PI*Math.Pow(Radius,2);
 Slices = (int)(Area / SliceSize);'
I want to take the diameter of the pizza and divide it by 2 which will give me the radius. How would i code that?

Answer (score 0):

```
//DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
        string Diameter = null;           //The diameter of the pizza which the user will enter
        int Slices;                       //The number of slices the user will get
        const double SliceSize = 14.125;  //The area of each slice of pizza
        double Radius;                    //The radius of the pizza
        double Area;                      //The area of the pizza


        //INPUT
        Console.Write("Enter diameter of pizza: ");
        Diameter = Console.ReadLine();
        double Diameter1 = Convert.ToDouble(Diameter);

        //PROCESS
        Radius = Diameter1 / 2;
        Area = Math.PI*Math.Pow(Radius,2);
        Slices = (int)Math.Round(Area / SliceSize);

        //OUTPUT
        Console.WriteLine("A " + Diameter + "\" pizza will yeild {0:n0} slices", Slices);


        // END - pause the program so the user can read the output and waits for user to press any key to exit the console
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```